Problema con matriz de correlación en Python
Cargo el conjunto de datos de kaggle heart diasease en la variable datos y a la hora de sacar las correlaciones entre variables, sólo me muestra los datos para la primera variable.
El código es el siguiente:
#Correlacion
corr = datos.drop(['TenYearCHD'],axis = 1).corr()

plt.figure(figsize = (10,8))
sns.heatmap(corr, cmap = 'coolwarm', annot = True, fmt = '.2f', center = 0,
       square = True,
       annot_kws = {'size' : 7},
       linewidth = .5)
plt.show()

¿Alguien tiene idea de porque ocurre esto? Os dejo una imagen de los que me sale por pantalla


Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Te invito a hacer el [tour]. Por favor, no publiques una nueva pregunta con el mismo contenido de esta otra anterior. En SO puedes editar tu pregunta para atender lo que te han comentado.

¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? Matriz de correlación en Python
